# What is the Void (conditional && action) in typescript

Tags: typescript, void

I have seen this syntax before, where I have something I want to do if a condition is true I would write it out like this.

```
() => void (x === 0 && this.setZero())
```

Why do you wrap `x === 0 && this.setZero()` in void?
What is the name of this pattern?

Void will return undefined but if `this.setZero()` returns undefined why not just do this?

```
() => x === 0 && this.setZero()
```

They both are valid ts. Is wrapping it with void just safer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a JavaScript thing.

`void` is a very strange JavaScript operator: It evaluates its operand, and then takes `undefined` as its result. So your

```
() => void (x === 0 && this.setZero())
```

...is an arrow function that will always return `undefined`, with the possible side-effect of calling `this.setZero()` (if `x === 0`).

> Why do you wrap x === 0 && this.setZero() in void?

So that the function **always** returns `undefined` rather than returning `false` (if `x === 0` is false) or the result of `this.setZero()` (if `x === 0` is `true`).

> What is the name of this pattern?

I don't think it has one, specifically.

Your `() => x === 0 && this.setZero()` alternative would return `false` or the result of `this.setZero()`.

I'll just note that

```
() => void (x === 0 && this.setZero())
```

does exactly what

```
() => { x === 0 && this.setZero(); }
```

does, since a verbose arrow function doesn't return anything unless you use `return`; another alternative would be:

```
() => { if (x === 0) this.setZero(); }
```

Comment: To explain why it might be used here, it's likely that this arrow function is being used in a promise continuation, and the developer specifically does *not* want to return either `false` or the result of `this.setZero()`, but simply have the promise/thenable be fulfilled with nothing. `void` is a very compact way to achieve this result.

Comment: @cdhowie: Heh, I'd just added that (but not the promise bit). Note that `void` is less compact than a verbose arrow would have been in this case.

Comment: While it's compact, it's obviously more confusing. Confusing code leads to bugs and maintenance problems. Better to be verbose and let minifiers do their thing.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: And in this case, there's a clearer more compact way (although I don't like abusing the `&&` operator). Heck, with a verbose arrow it's even shorter if you don't: `() => { if (x === 0) this.setZero(); }` :-)

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you mean by "confusing." Were I to stumble onto this code, the `void` operator makes it 100% clear to me that the developer wanted this function to return undefined. Were the developer to use the verbose arrow function syntax, I would be left wondering if using the verbose form was a mistake and they actually did want to return some value. (Using the verbose form with an `if` block instead of using the `&&` operator would clear that up, though.)

Comment: Cool, this makes a lot more sense. I agree its not that good of a pattern to follow.